# Configure a hudson maven job to keep building if there are test failures, but only deploy if there are no test failures

Tags: maven-2, maven, hudson, maven-3, jenkins

I've created a hudson job for our maven multi-project with 5 modules to deploy the `SNAPSHOT` artifacts to the maven repository. That's ok, as long as it builds successfully without test failures. However, now I'd like to fulfill the following requirements:

- When a module has a test failure, the build should continue bulding and test the other modules, but turn yellow. Using `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true` accomplishes, but fails at the next requirement.
- **When a module has a test failure, none of the artifacts should be deployed to the maven repository.** Other projects depend on the snapshots this project and those projects only want to use *the latest snapshots that don't have any failing tests*.
- Preferably, use the hudson maven integration instead of a free script we get the hudson report pages (red/yellow/blue status per module, build log error coloring, ...). Specifically running the maven build twice (first `mvn test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true`, than `mvn deploy -DskipTests`) is not a solution because it's a performance loss and it confuses the hudson report pages and it's not atomic (it updates from the repositories again in the second build).

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an post build option called *Deploy artifacts to Maven repository*. If you do not select *Deploy even if the build is unstable*, then that mean if test fails, it won't deploy anything. Together with the `-fae` in the command, thing should work in your desired way

Comment: Pitfall: The option *Deploy artifacts to Maven repository* is not available in a freestyle hudson job, only in a maven2 hudson job (which apparently doesn't work yet for maven 3).

Comment: By now a maven2 hudson/jenkins build does support maven3

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try use **mvn -fae** option with you jobs on hudson - it make maven fail only after full build

Comment: The -fae option (fail at end), doesn't stop the deploying I presume. But it looks like a better alternative than -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If build time isn't a problem for you, I think the better option is to create another job, just for deploying. Something like this:

1. Configure your original job (let's call it "build job") with "mvn -fae clean install"
2. Create a new job ("deploy job") with "mvn deploy", and don't configure any *Build triggers* for it
3. In the "build job", enable the *Build other projects* option, under *Post-build actions* and set it to run your "deploy job".

Maybe you can try to configure both jobs to use the same workspace, saving some time on the whole build/deploy process.

Comment: By using a free script instead of the maven integration this can be done in a single job, but *Specifically running the maven build twice (first mvn test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true, than mvn deploy -DskipTests) is not a solution because it's a performance loss and it confuses the hudson report pages and it's not atomic (it updates from the repositories again in the second build).*

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/products.php) as a repository manager, you can use the [Hudson/Jenkins Artifactory plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin) to deploy your artifacts. This plugin will only deploy your artifacts if all tests pass for all modules of a Maven build.

Comment: Interesting solution. We're using Nexus though, but I 'll take a look if they have something similar.