# Keeping the maven deploy plugin from deploying on test failures

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

I'm a long time user of the `maven-release-plugin` which will not release (aka deploy jars to maven repo) if there are unit test failures.

For various reasons I want to use only the maven deploy plugin but apparently will still deploy even if there are test failures in the `maven-surefire-plugin`.

Consequently instead of just

```
mvn clean deploy
```

I must setup my CI to do a two step analagous to (shell):

```
mvn clean test && mvn deploy -DskipTests=true
```

I have made sure surefire is not set to ignore failures. Ideally I would not like to run two separate processes.

Certainly deployment on test failures can't be the default? Am I missing something?

**EDIT it appears to be a Jenkins issue.. Can't reproduce**

I'm not sure why or how Jenkins forces the maven build to continue on test failure (I assume this is for reporting) but it doesn't show any of the options being passed to for it to continue. It appears to only happen when Jenkins says "Modules changed, recalculating dependency graph".

Comment: What's your CI server? Jenkins? How did you make sure test failures are ignored? Also, your second step doesn't need to invoke the `deploy` phase, it could simply be e.g. `mvn jar:jar deploy:deploy` (given the project was a jar) as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38148135/5606016). Moreover, it should be an additional CI job step, not an inline `&&` command.

Comment: deploy won't work if test phase fails, you must have something wrong in your configuration

Comment: Yes it is Jenkins. It is an additional CI job step (hence I said analogous to the shell command). And `mvn deploy:deploy` is equivalent to `mvn deploy`. I'm not sure how `mvn jar:jar deploy:deploy` is any better. And no I don't want test failures to be ignored. I checked effective pom. There appears there isn't any surefire plugin way to kill the build on test failure.

Comment: It appears that it is Jenkins. I can't figure out why Jenkins just continues the build.

Comment: It's a known feature, on test failures the jenkins maven build is set to unstable and not failed. If you use a free style jenkins job for the same, the build will instead fail.

Comment: @A_Di-Matteo Answer with that comment and  I will mark it correct. I'm not sure why I can't reproduce it anymore with Jenkins but I believe you are correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are encountering a known issue (or feature, depending on tastes) of Jenkins, which in Maven builds (hence created from the Maven Jenkins job template) would always pass by default `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true` to the concerned Maven build, mainly because it would set the status of the build to `UNSTABLE` and not `FAILED` in case of test failures.

This behavior has already been tacked in different Stack Overflow threads, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683518/how-do-i-make-jenkins-build-fail-when-maven-unit-tests-fail) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196203/configure-a-hudson-maven-job-to-keep-building-if-there-are-test-failures-but-on) for some references, and it is also an [open ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24655) (providing detailed description) on the Jenkins JIRA platform, although since already a while and would probably not be fixed (or at least clarified in the job configuration UI).

However, the behavior is not provided when creating a Maven build from a freestyle Jenkins job template, that is, using a template which is not already pre-configured for Maven and hence no `maven.test.failure` property would be passed by default.

The guideline indeed is to not deploy artifacts in case of test failures (which is the default behavior of the `maven-surefire-plugin` btw), which you can tackle in different ways:

- Using a freestyle Jenkins job template and hence taking full control over the Maven build execution, although giving up on some nice pre-configuration
- Keep the Maven Jenkins job and explicitly pass the `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false` option as part of the initial `mvn clean deploy` command
- Split the job in several build steps and only execute the next one if the previous was strictly successful (and not successful/unstable). A first step would be the classic `mvn clean install`, leaving then a next step to deploy either via Maven (see next) or a Jenkins plugin (there are Artifactory/Nexus Jenkins plugin which handle this task nicely, with the direct advantage of easier credentials and repositories management for snapshot/releases and hence more governance/security on CI side, removing noise from the `pom.xml` file or from every developer's maven settings).

Concerning the additional Maven step which would only deploy, some considerations to also address some points in the comments above:

There is a relevant [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607834/maven-lifecycle-vs-phase-vs-plugin-vs-goal) between `mvn deploy` and `mvn deploy:deploy`, where the former is invoking a Maven phase and hence in cascade [each phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) from `validate` till `deploy` (hence, `compile`, `test`, `package`, e.g.) and each and every potential plugin execution configured in the pom file for a certain phase; the latter instead is only invoking a goal, the `deploy` goal of the `maven-deploy-plugin`, with the obvious direct advantage of performances (it's only performing one quick action and not the whole build again) and concerns (it's only performing what we actually really want at this stage).

Yes, you can skip tests and the `maven-jar-plugin` would not re-package the application once again, e.g., and further default optimization provided by Maven, but still the former would be much slower and less correct.
However, `deploy:deploy` would not work because of missing information in the Maven build context, looking simply at the `target` folder would not be enough to identify what to deploy, Maven needs to know which artifact is attached to the current build to be deployed. The additional `jar:jar` comes to the rescue in this case, not re-packaging anything but simply detecting what it was supposed to be packaged, attaching it as an artifact to the build context and making the `maven-deploy-plugin` happy. This mechanism is also explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308162/maven-the-packaging-for-this-project-did-not-assign-a-file-to-the-build-artifac/38148135#38148135) Stack Overflow answer, as previously pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Great answer--for reference in new versions of Jenkins (maven integration plugin?) there is a post-build action "Deploy to Maven repository" that works, but requires that the repository be explicitly configured in the plugin or pom, so it's not as good as adding a post-build deploy:deploy step, which honors settings.xml etc. :/